# How to connect to Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Good day.

I want to write an app for the work with builds and bugs in Team Services, previously Visual Studio Online (VSO). I've found the REST API, and it works, but it's not too comfortable to work with JSON. Is there any SDK for Team Services, or is that possible to connect to Team Services using standard TFS libraries from Microsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) to connect to VSTS just like how you connect to on-premise TFS. But if you are working with vNext build, I would recommend you to use the "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" in the webpage which still use Rest API to connect to TFS since the client libraries API only support some basic operation with vNext build.